# MySQL order by distinct items first

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table of item possessions which is something like this:

```
item_possession
===============
id      product_id      status
1       50 (weapon)     available
2       50 (weapon)     unavailable
3       10 (shield)     unavailable
4       10 (shield)     unavailable
5       50 (weapon)     available
6       20 (helmet)     available
7       20 (helmet)     available
8       50 (weapon)     available
9       50 (weapon)     available
10      30 (thunder)    unavailable
11      20 (helmet)     available
```

*Note: This is a game and I can own duplicated products (I can sell them), please note that I can have different rows referencing the same item.*

Is it possible to order my item possessions listing the **distinct item first** (I don't care the order, I can just use the table ID) and the duplicates at the end?

Something like this:

```
item_possession
===============
id      product_id      status
1       50 (weapon)     available
3       10 (shield)     unavailable
6       20 (helmet)     available
8       30 (thunder)    unavailable
2       50 (weapon)     unavailable
4       10 (shield)     unavailable
5       50 (weapon)     available
7       20 (helmet)     available
8       50 (weapon)     available
9       50 (weapon)     available
10      30 (thunder)    unavailable
11      20 (helmet)     available
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or, old school...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM item_possession x 
  JOIN item_possession y 
    ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id 
 ORDER 
    BY COUNT(*)
     , id;
```

EDIT: Actually, you seem to want this...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM item_possession x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(id) id FROM item_possession GROUP BY product_id ) y
    ON y.id = x.id
  ORDER 
   BY y.id IS NULL,x.id;
```

For further help, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This _almost_ works! Could you please explain me the logic behind this? The only problem is that I would like the standard order after the first batch of distinct items. Your query is returning correctly the first items but then it tries to arrange the following in order to make them distinct again. Is it possible to avoid this? I updated the example in order to show the desired output!

Comment: Your second answer works perfectly! You are truly an SQL wizard :) Unfortunately I am not able to fully understand it.

Comment: Ohhh, I break it apart with various tests and I finally understood it (FALSE = 0 and TRUE = 1). You TRULY are an SQL magician! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by product_id order by id)
```

There is no need to put this in the `select`.  You can also do this using a subquery in older versions:

```
order by (select count(*)
          from item_possession t2
          where t2.product_id = t.product_id and t2.id <= t.id
         )
```

Alternatively, you can use variables -- which requires sorting twice:

```
select ip.*
from (select ip.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = ip.product_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@p := ip.product_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select ip.* from item_possession ip order by ip.product_id, ip.id
           ) ip cross join
           (select @p := -1, @rn := 0) params
     ) ip
order by rn, id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by product_id order by id) as seq
from table t
order by seq, id;
```

Comment: This is giving me `Syntax error: unexpected '(' (opening parenthesis)`: `select t.*, row_number() over (partition by product_id order by id) as seq
from item_possession t
order by seq, id;`